# SQL ignore certain rows based on characters

Tags: sql, db2

I have following data:

```
   NAME 1               NAME2  
NAME SURNAME       NAME SURNAME(AI)    
NAME1 SURNAME1     NAME1 SURNAME1(101)
MICHAEL BEUM       MICHAEL BEUM(114)
MICHAEL BAUM       MICHAEL BEUM
```

Query is comparing similar names in the same table. How can you ignore rows that contains following characters: (AI), (101), (114)...? There is fmr.name, fmr.surname, fmr.name_surname columns and unique id for every name_surname. I tried NOT LIKE and LIKE CONCAT, and I still get this rows in result. (DB 10.5)

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the NOT LIKE version you tried ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use DB2 10.5, thanks.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus Hi, it is

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE
NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(AI)%' AND NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(101)%' AND NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(114)%' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE
NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(AI)%' AND NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(101)%' AND NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(114)%' ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(AI)%'
        OR NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(101)%'
        OR NAME2 NOT LIKE '%(114)%';
```